.htaccess redirect to different domain specific to one folder and its sub directories
I set up a redirect that checks local domain for folder and redirect if not found keeping structure.  Problem I am having is it needs to be specific to just the "pictures" directory and sub folders.  Right now it is redirecting entire root and all subs not just pictures folder.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!
/root
-/pictures
--/gallery1
--/gallery2
--/gallery3

This is the code I have so far.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /pictures
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) https://archive.com/$1 [R=302,L]

Original goal that redirects as it should.  Need folder specific.
https//webpage.com/pictures/outdoors ------------> https//archive.com/pictures/outdoors             
https//webpage.com/pictures/outdoors/ -----------> https//archive.com/pictures/outdoors/    
https//webpage.com/pictures/outdoors/index.php --> https//archive.com/pictures/outdoors/index.php   

RewriteBase /pictures does not work as expected.

Well, looks to me that all you need to add is a slightly more precise pattern to what requested path you want to apply your rule to:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?pictures/(.*)$ https://archive.com/pictures/$1 [R=302,L]

You can simplify that, since you do not want to alter the requested path:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?pictures/ https://archive.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

Note: I personally like a leading /? in path matching patterns in a RewriteRule. That allows the same rule to be used in the central configuration of the http server's virtual host or, without modification, in a decentralized configuration file (typically called ".htaccess").

Works like a champ!  I went with the second one.  Simple sounds good to me.  Thanks again for the help!
